# Need to cover negative test scenario in test method

Tags: apex

[image: Uncovered line]If a user enters a mob no with more than 11 digit, then the error is displayed using custom label.I'm not able to cover that only line..

Kindly suggest

Thanks :)

Comment: Paste your code in correct format. Not able to vie the link

Comment: It looks like your validation only works if the mobile number starts with '44'. But in your test class, the greater-than-11-digit mobile number does not start with 44 and hence these lines are not covered.

Comment: if(temp.length < 11 || temp.length > 11), the condition clearly says the mobile number can only be 11 digits. Why are you expecting the test data to cover it by entering the number which is greater than 11 digits?

Answer (score 0):

Please insert a contact's mobile number in your test class that starts with '44' and having size not equals to 11

```
contact conObj;
conObj.Lastname = 'Test';
conObj.Mobilephone = 441234567890;
insert conObj;
```